# add animate.css class when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animate.css

I have a full-screen div (#loader) as that shall be removed using an [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) effect. I am using some effects on text and it works great. But my full-screen div does not `bounceOutDown` when the page is fully loaded. I have tried to use jQuery [.addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) for this. This is the code (placed in the footer) I am using

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#loader').addClass('animated bounceOutDown');
});
```

```css
#loader {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  -webkit-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
  animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader">

  LOADING

</div>
```

Have a look at my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gobLcnx5/36/). What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS.

Comment: Are you loading the jQuery Library? Do you see any errors in console? You do not need to add it to the footer since you are using `.ready()`.

Comment: Are you aware the the jQuery code `.addClass('animated bounceOutDown');` does not give it the effect `bounceOutDown`, rather it gives the classes `animated` and `bounceOutDown`

Comment: jQuery works great for other stuff on my page, like fadeOut...

Comment: I am using `.click();('animated bounceOutDown');` somewhere else on the page which makes the div `bounceOutDown`.

Comment: You can do a whole bunch of other stuff with animate.css when you combine it with jQuery or add your own CSS rules. Dynamically add animations using jQuery with ease (https://github.com/daneden/animate.css): `$('#yourElement').addClass('animated bounceOutLeft');`

Comment: Do you also require jqueryui? EX: <script src="https: //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: I wonder if the animate.css code isn't compatible with the kind of positioning  and sizing of #loader?

Comment: @Dejan.S Did so

Comment: Just added a https://jsfiddle.net/gobLcnx5/36/

Answer (score 0):

animated and bounceDown classes added to #Loader element but because you use animation property in css file, code inside animated and bounceDown classes are overwritten and don't work.

[image]